# IOS open application in virtual space

Tags: ios, memory

Essentially I'm looking to make an app which works sorta like cheat engine. Is there any way to load another application into the memory of my own app in order to read the memory that way? Are there alternative ways to easily read memory from another app without jailbreaking?

Comment: read the memory of another app? I sure hope not. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: nope, cannot be done. All apps are sand boxed ... no one can access another apps data

Comment: Not exactly reading the memory of the app directly, sandboxing is obvious. What I mean is to essentially load the app into the memory space of your own app and run it there in a virtual environment in order to read your own apps memory. But I need to know if there's a way to do that